# Android - Listview Background Problem

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem, and i know that the answer properly is pretty simple, but I've tried everything at the moment, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. In my project I've got the following layouts:
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="3dp">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:background="@layout/customtabshape"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80px"
            android:layout_alignBottom = "@android:id/tabcontent"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

nyheder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="80px">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/tv2sport" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/feedtitle" />
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="0px" 
    android:layout_height="0px" 
    android:id="@+id/feeddescribtion"/>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="0px" 
    android:layout_height="0px" 
    android:id="@+id/feedpubdate"/>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="0px" 
    android:layout_height="0px" 
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:id="@+id/feedlink"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listtitle"
    android:textSize="24px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listpubdate"
    android:textSize="20px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

rsslist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="25px"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
```

My problem is, that I want the same background texture everywhere. I can get it anywhere but the list itself.

According to this article
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html

and multiple others, I should be able to fix my problem with black background in the list, by using android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" inside the list. But I've almost tried putting that line everywhere, and the background in the list is still black.
What am I doing wrong?
(I know that there is no background at the moment, I did that not to make things more complicated).

Comment: you want to put same background everywhere inside tab also..?

Comment: if you set a background for the root linearlayout and set the listview's background and rows's background to `#00000000`, it might work and you will have a background for the whole activity.

Comment: @Lalit Poptani
No inside the tab i use a speciel .xml, and that's not making trouble. I just can't get the background inside the list. Everywhere else it works.

Comment: @Sherif
I've already tried that, as that will be logical. But it's stil black inside the list :(

Comment: use android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" in ListView in xml..

Comment: Is your ListActivity a part of Tab? If yes then try putting android:background="#FFFFFF" to TabHost.

Comment: I've tried both of your solutions, and none of them work.
Is my problem inside the row.mxl inside the two textviews? It is those two fields causing the problem.
But I've tried anything inside these fields, and nothing happends.

Comment: While me RSS is loading the background got the right texture, so that must be correct, but as soon as the list appears the background is black.
I've searched 20+ pages just telling to put android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" inside the listview, but noting happens.

Comment: Just an idea, try putting transparent background for the framelayout in main.xml.

Comment: I found a solution. It was because I'm retarded.
Inside my activity I was forcing the background color in MyCustom Adapter:

    listTitle.setBackgroundColor(0xff101010);
    listPubdate.setBackgroundColor(0xff101010);

Which make it impossible to use android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" inside the listview of course.

I've deleted the above code inside my activity, and now it works. Sorry for wasting your time! That was the one thing I haven't thought about.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just add

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

in ListView in xml file.